# Prompt for Access Code each time a person accesses a document

Tags: api, docusignapi, signer

Our DocuSign users are accessing documents by clicking on a link in an email.  We have specified an AccessCode on each recipient.  A recipient may be listed more than once in a workflow.  For example:

Person A (signs)
Person B (fills in information and approves)
Person C (signs)
Person B (fills in information and approves)

Each person is prompted for the Access Code.  However, Person B is not prompted for the Access Code the second time he/she accesses the document.

**Is there a way we can have a recipient (signer) be prompted each time the document is viewed via the email link?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can meet the requirement you describe by doing the following:

1. Login to the DocuSign web console (as an Administrator).
2. Navigate to **Preferences** >> **Features**.
3. In the Dropdown List labeled **Authenticate on return access to envelope**, select the value "Each Access".
4. Click the **Save** button (located all the way at the bottom of the Features page).

Note: this is an Account-level setting, so it will apply to all envelopes that are sent in the DocuSign account.  More information about Authentication configuration can be found here:  http://www.docusign.com/support/how-to-guides/authentication-options.

[image: authentication setting]

**Additional suggestion:**
You might also try setting a unique Access Code each time a Recipient appears in the Routing Order.  For example, if person B appears in the routing order twice -- once as #2 and again as #4 -- set person B's access code to "1234" in Routing Order 2, and to "5678" in Routing Order 4.  In my (somewhat limited) testing, doing this resulted in the Recipient being prompted for Access Code each time.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick.  I also have the other options set as: Authentication Required: Optional; Authentication Expiration:  Always

Comment: I've modified my answer to add another suggestion:  You might also try setting a unique Access Code each time a Recipient appears in the Routing Order.  For example, if person B appears in the routing order twice -- once as #2 and again as #4 -- set person B's access code to "1234" in Routing Order 2, and to "5678" in Routing Order 4.  In my (somewhat limited) testing, doing this resulted in the Recipient being prompted for Access Code each time.